# Use IdentityUser in existing project with separate database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to add Identity to my project but I need to link the IdentityUser with my project. My project has his own database and Identity has his own database, I want to keep it this way. How do I link the IdentityUser to my objects in the other database. For example the user has reactions.

Comment: You can have two dbcontexts in your application and use it for specific purpose. Like you can use dbContext1 for application database operation and dbContext2 for Identity user management, for this you can use EntityFramework. have you tried like this ? Please elaborate more what you tried.